# Imported project invisible

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the [Market Billing](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/market_billing_r01.zip) sample, unzipped it and used `Create project from existing source` to add it to my workspace.

(for those wondering why I didn't use `Import Existing Projects into Workspace`, I did try that first, but Eclipse won't find it and thus won't enable the `Next` button)

No error or warning was issued, but... I can't see it on Eclipse's Project Explorer!

The interesting thing is that it does exist in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects`.

Why does this happen?

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working with Working Sets by any chance?

Make sure you select Edit Working Set, then add the newly created project to the active Working Set.

Comment: Good catch. Interestingly enough, this formal sample from Google comes with a `Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized` warning in `PurchaseObserver`.